# Remove a word from a line if the word contains a particular pattern in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a line say "append serial=xyx end";
I will search the line for "serial" and if it is present in the line I was to remove until the next space character from current position. 
The line will look like:
"append end" after the operations are completed

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
my $string = "append serial=xyx end";
$string =~ s/serial\=.*\s+//;
warn $string;
```

OUTPUT:

```
append end at test.pl line 3.
```

Comment: ... or non-greedy `s/\bserial=.*?\s+//;` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
s/serial\S*//
```

Literally, match following and replace it with empty string:

1. `serial`
2. `\S` non-space
3. `*` zero or more times